# Как работает рынок assembler программистов? Стоит ли осваивать 8051?

Tags: ассемблер, 8051

Уважаемые коллеги. В университете изучаем контроллер 8051, и то как с ним работать. Очень интересно, но я не совсем понимаю, пригодится ли мне это знание на рынке? Я так понимаю, что работа на дне программирования происходит так: Программист осваивает 2-3 контроллера, и ищет по ним вакансии, или осваивает их уже непосредственно при приёме на работу, а потом работает по ним лет 10-15-20-25, пока или он или эти микроконтроллеры не устареют). Правильно ли я понимаю это?.
Посоветуйте пожалуйста какие простые контроллеры лучше освоить начинающему, что бы стать востребованным на рынке как можно раньше. Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Comment: Неправильно понимаешь

Comment: Откровенно говоря, в мире контроллеров и bare metal ассемблер, конечно, приветствуется, но большая часть кода пишется на Си. А еще, читайте основы -- http://easyelectronics.ru/files/Book/digital-design-and-computer-architecture-russian-translation.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зная один контроллер, ты будешь знать много, и сможешь бытро разобраться с любым другим. Поэтому не теряй время, изучай, и как можно лучше и глубже.

Сейчас ты не просто изучаешь какой-то конкретный контроллер, а изучаешь общие принципы устройства контроллеров (процессоров) и компьютеров. Все остальные работают примерно также.

И посвяти время изучению различных типовых алгоритмов программирования.